# Advanced aliasing for csh shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, csh

I want to create an alias for the `nedit` command but with the ability to add a `.txt` automatically to the passed argument. For example, when I would type ***n newfile*** --> it should execute --> ***nedit newfile.txt***.

In other words, "**n (file_name)**" should automatically give me `file_name`.txt

Currently, I'm using **alias n "nedit"**.

Please let me know if this can be done within the CSH shell.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006343/creating-alias-in-linux

Answer (score 5):

Aliases in the `csh` shell are slightly more advanced than aliases in `sh`-like shells.

To create an alias `n` that calls `nedit` with the given filename and that adds a `.txt` extension to that filename, you may do something like

```
alias n nedit \!:1.txt
```

`!:1` will be replaced by the first command line argument after the alias name when invoking the alias.  The `!` has to be escaped as `\!` to not trigger history expansion.

For more information about `csh` and `tcsh` aliases, see ["Writing Aliases in csh and tcsh"](http://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html) (a site external to U&L).

Comment: yes!!! yeah your suggestion is working pretty fine. for the above alias requirement. i mean let say i entered "nedit newfile.txt" then automatically it should add & to command and execute nedit newfile.txt &"

Comment: if i have to add "&" to all commands automatically then how to do so?

Comment: @AshokKumarMishra I don't think you would actually want to add `&` to the end of all commands, do you?  This is furthermore a separate question.

Comment: in my usage in almost every where

Comment: @AshokKumarMishra Please ask a separate question about this. It does not seem related to this question here. When you ask the new question, please also clarify it with examples as I'm not sure I fully understand it.